# Update many-to-many relation with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I'm curious if it's possible to update a bunch of records in a join table that's not registered in an ActiveRecord as a model.

I have 2 classes, lets say A and B, joined by table AsBs.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :A_name, :B_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :Bs, join_table: :AsBs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :B_name, :A_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :As, join_table: :AsBs
end

class CreateAsBs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :AsBs, id: :false do |t|
      t.integer :A_id
      t.integer :B_id
    end
   end
end
```

I also have a form with checkboxes for B records, which returns a params hash like the one below

```
params[:my_form]
>> { "B_name_1" => "1", "B_name_2" => "0", "B_name_3" => "0"} 

#What means the user has chosen only first checkbox
```

What I need is to update the A-B relations, using that params hash or other custom hash based on it's content. 
Eventually I need this simple example to create a

```
A_id | B_id
  1  |  1
```

record in my :AsBs table and remove 1-2 and 1-3 records, if any.

I obviously can create an AsBs model and edit it manually, but I'd expect using 
something like update / update_all / update_attributes for @a.Bs or @a.B_ids

Any advice?

Comment: It looks like you're over-riding a lot of Rails defaults. Unless you have a very compelling reason for doing this, it's best to stick to convention. Adding exceptions without a good reason makes your application more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Looking half a year back I wonder how so simple approach was made through a so complicated way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should be able to do

```
@b.as = [@a]
@b.save
```